# How do I output the entire asset pipeline in rails?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, asset-pipeline

For this particular rails project, I want to save on an http request, so I'd like to output all the javascript onto the body that has been in the rails asset pipeline.

Is there a way to do this in rails?

Comment: What are you asking for here? What does "all the JavaScript onto the body" mean?

Comment: @tadman instead of having javascript be in a external file and an http request is being made, i'd rather output all the javascript in the http message body in the html.

Comment: Ah so you mean as an inline `<script>` tag. Got it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You unfortunately won't be able to get this working easily in development since the files are being served live by [Sprocket's server](https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets/blob/master/lib/sprockets/server.rb), but getting this working in production is fairly simple: you just need to loop over the compiled scripts and render them in a blob.

Here's a helper that you can use instead of `javascript_include_tag` which will do just that:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  if Rails.env.production?
    def embedded_javascript_include_tag(*sources)
      options = sources.extract_options!.stringify_keys
      scripts = sources.uniq.map { |source|
        File.read("#{Rails.root}/public/#{javascript_path(source)}")
      }.join("\n").html_safe
      content_tag(:script, scripts, options)
    end
  else
    def embedded_javascript_include_tag(*sources)
      javascript_include_tag(sources)
    end
  end
end
```

Note you'll still need to run `rake assets:precompile` for this to work. Don't forget to set the environment to enable any uglifiers and minifers! (`RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile`)

Comment: Do you know if this will obfuscate and minify the javascript? I think it does but I am not sure.

Comment: This is just serving up whatever comes out of `rake assets:precompile`, so assuming you've set up everything in `production.rb` appropriately, they should be compiled.